# Wifi issues after disconnecting from nordvpn

Tags: wireless, network-manager, internet

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.6, and my network controller is a intel corporation wireless 3165 version 79 logical name wlp3s0 (hope that’s the right info)

I was connected to a P2P network through nordvpn over night with killswitch active , and this morning I noticed I couldn’t connect to the internet. When I checked nordvpn status it said it was connected with an uptime of 18+ hours, but when I tried to disconnect it stalled for several minutes and eventually I just force quit the application.

I assumed that I had triggered the kill switch at some point but I thought reconnecting to my wifi would be pretty straightforward. Here is what I have tried so far:

1. restarted my computer - wifi still just showing question mark
2. forget network , reconnect - wifi status symbol still a question mark

Here’s where it gets weird

3)wifi settings > privacy > set connectivity checking off and then I restart connection. At this point it LOOKS like I should be connected to the wifi. The connectivity symbol is the wifi arcs indicating strength…yet I still can’t ping Google…

I apologize for the formatting, I’m doing this on my potato phone because , well, no connectivity on my laptop. I would greatly appreciate any help in trouble shooting :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok well I feel dumb. I wasn’t aware that the killswitch would continue to run through system restart…but I guess that’s a sign of a really good kill switch! I just had to run the command to turn off the killswitch and all was fixed.